# Why is my Deep Q Network not learning to play a simple game?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning

So i have made a small python game where the player have to reach the end and avoid the traps, And it looks like this

[image]

I have tried many different batch sizes, Rewards, Input shapes, Amount of nodes in the hidden layer, But the network is still not training.

The current way i'm training it, Is using 64 batch size with 100000 memory size, The input is a 1D array representing the game state + the player's coordinates + the amount of moves left before the game ends, And the reward starts at -distanceFromEnd + maxDistance / 2, If you reach the end you get +500 reward and the game is done, If you touch a trap you get a -100 reward and the game is done, If the game is not done in 64 moves you get a -200 reward and the game is done.

i'm using AdamOptimizer and MSE loss function, And for the activation functions i'm using ReLU for all the layers except the last layer i'm using nothing.

the player, end, traps positions are all randomized after each episode

The average score (score is the sum of the rewards) for the last 100 games is around -30 even after 3000 episodes.
The DQN is working fine on the gym game LunarLander-v2.
And as i said i have been trying to tweak the values but it didn't help.

First here are the labels that i use in the state

```
  FLOOR = 1
  END = 2
  TRAP = 3
  PLAYER = 4
```

This is my step function

```
 def step(self, action):
isDone = False
if action == 0:
  # Move Up
  if self.playerY != 0:
    self.playerY -= 1
elif action == 1:
  # Move Down
  if self.playerY != 7:
    self.playerY += 1
elif action == 2:
  # Move Right
  if self.playerX != 0:
    self.playerX -= 1
elif action == 3:
  # Move Left
  if self.playerX != 7:
    self.playerX += 1

x = self.playerX - self.endX
x = x * x
y = self.playerY - self.endY
y = y * y

distance = math.sqrt(x + y)
reward = -distance + self.maxDist
#self.lastDist = distance

if self.state[self.playerX, self.playerY] == self.END:
  reward = 500
  isDone = True
elif self.state[self.playerX, self.playerY] == self.TRAP:
  reward = -100
  isDone = True

self.moves -= 1

if self.moves < 0:
  reward = -200
  isDone = True

return self.getFlatState(), reward, isDone, 0
```

State Getter function

```
  # Adding one to the players coordinates to avoid 0s as a try to fix the problem
  def getFlatState(self):
     return np.concatenate([np.ndarray.flatten(self.state), [self.playerX + 1, self.playerY + 1, self.moves]])
```

Here's the DQN/Agent script

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

class ReplayBuffer():
def __init__(self, max_size, input_dims):
    self.mem_size = max_size
    self.mem_cntr = 0

    self.state_memory = np.zeros((self.mem_size, *input_dims), 
                                dtype=np.float32)
    self.new_state_memory = np.zeros((self.mem_size, *input_dims),
                            dtype=np.float32)
    self.action_memory = np.zeros(self.mem_size, dtype=np.int32)
    self.reward_memory = np.zeros(self.mem_size, dtype=np.float32)
    self.terminal_memory = np.zeros(self.mem_size, dtype=np.int32)

def store_transition(self, state, action, reward, state_, done):
    index = self.mem_cntr % self.mem_size
    self.state_memory[index] = state
    self.new_state_memory[index] = state_
    self.reward_memory[index] = reward
    self.action_memory[index] = action
    self.terminal_memory[index] = 1 - int(done)
    self.mem_cntr += 1

def sample_buffer(self, batch_size):
    max_mem = min(self.mem_cntr, self.mem_size)
    batch = np.random.choice(max_mem, batch_size, replace=False)

    states = self.state_memory[batch]
    states_ = self.new_state_memory[batch]
    rewards = self.reward_memory[batch]
    actions = self.action_memory[batch]
    terminal = self.terminal_memory[batch]

    return states, actions, rewards, states_, terminal

def build_dqn(lr, n_actions, input_dims, fc1_dims, fc2_dims):
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(fc1_dims, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(fc2_dims, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(n_actions, activation=None)])
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=lr), loss='mean_squared_error')

return model

class Agent():
def __init__(self, lr, gamma, n_actions, epsilon, batch_size,
            input_dims, epsilon_dec=1e-3, epsilon_end=0.01,
            mem_size=1000000, fname='dqn_model.h5'):
    self.action_space = [i for i in range(n_actions)]
    self.gamma = gamma
    self.epsilon = epsilon
    self.eps_dec = epsilon_dec
    self.eps_min = epsilon_end
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.model_file = fname
    self.memory = ReplayBuffer(mem_size, input_dims)
    self.q_eval = build_dqn(lr, n_actions, input_dims, 256, 128)

def store_transition(self, state, action, reward, new_state, done):
    self.memory.store_transition(state, action, reward, new_state, done)

def choose_action(self, observation):
    if np.random.random() < self.epsilon:
        action = np.random.choice(self.action_space)
    else:
        state = np.array([observation])
        actions = self.q_eval.predict(state)

        action = np.argmax(actions)

    return action

def learn(self):
    if self.memory.mem_cntr < self.batch_size:
        return

    states, actions, rewards, states_, dones = \
            self.memory.sample_buffer(self.batch_size)

    q_eval = self.q_eval.predict(states)
    q_next = self.q_eval.predict(states_)


    q_target = np.copy(q_eval)
    batch_index = np.arange(self.batch_size, dtype=np.int32)

    q_target[batch_index, actions] = rewards + \
                    self.gamma * np.max(q_next, axis=1)*dones


    self.q_eval.train_on_batch(states, q_target)

    self.epsilon = self.epsilon - self.eps_dec if self.epsilon > \
             self.eps_min else self.eps_min

def save_model(self):
    self.q_eval.save(self.model_file)


def load_model(self):
    self.q_eval = load_model(self.model_file)
```

Comment: @desertnaut https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ms2nudZuho1xnwc6yXDwQo8JbEKzhttH

Comment: Hmm... A minor question - how many times (in its random exploratory state) has it reached its goal? Are you using an epsilon greedy strategy? your question did not mention it...

Comment: @neelg yes im using an epsilon greed which starts at 1 and decay to 0.01, its reaching the goal like 5% of the time but i think since i reward getting close to the goal it should just learn to go to the goal

Comment: i've added the DQN/Agent code to the question

Comment: You say that the goal and the initial position of the agent is randomly created? Could you first try it with a static obstacle, then we can further isolate the problem by studying the behavior of the agent. Right now, there are so many factors that it is becoming difficult to pinpoint the solution...

Comment: @neelg i did as you said and it still didn't start winning consistently even after 800 epochs, but then i made the position of the end static too and it started to win 90% of the times

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the goal state position and the initial position of the agent was not stationary. When they are fixed as reported by OP the agent starts winning consistently about "90% of the time".

Though far from perfect I wouldn't expect much from a naive DQN. Using more advanced techniques like A3C or even DDQN (Double Deep Q learning) should help you solve it. As we use a bit more advanced techniques to start to solve even more complex problems.

small and easy tasks with not much future planning could be done with some more diverse methods such as 'Monte-Carlo'. But the main problem here is that your obstacles are randomly generated and the simple DQN does not formulate in advance what path it should take to avoid the `red areas` which give a negative reward.

DQN is essentially Q-learning but values are stored in a more compressed state so to accommodate a bit more than possible. So it is not reliable for such complex solutions (as said before). So simply put the solution is to just use more complex and new methods, many of which I have mentioned.